# How to check if rows in one column present in another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data set = data1 with id and emails as follows:

```
id  emails
1   A,B,C,D,E
2   F,G,H,A,C,D
3   I,K,L,T
4   S,V,F,R,D,S,W,A
5   P,A,L,S
6   Q,W,E,R,F
7   S,D,F,E,Q
8   Z,A,D,E,F,R
9   X,C,F,G,H
10  A,V,D,S,C,E
```

I have another data set = data2 with check_email as follows:

```
check_email
A
D
S
V
```

I want to check if check_email column is present in data1 and want to take only those id from data1 when check_email in data2 is present in emails in data1.

My desired output will be:

```
id
1
2
4
5
7
8
10
```

I have created a code using for loop but it is taking forever because my actual dataset is very large.
Any advice in this regard will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to subset your data. First collapse everything in one pattern:

```
paste(data2$check_email, collapse = "|")
# [1] "A|D|S|V"
```

Then create a indicator vector whether the pattern matches the emails:

```
grep(paste(data2$check_email, collapse = "|"), data1$emails)
# [1]  1  2  4  5  7  8 10
```

And then combine everything:

```
data1[grep(paste(data2$check_email, collapse = "|"), data1$emails), ]

#   id          emails
# 1  1       A,B,C,D,E
# 2  2     F,G,H,A,C,D
# 3  4 S,V,F,R,D,S,W,A
# 4  5         P,A,L,S
# 5  7       S,D,F,E,Q
# 6  8     Z,A,D,E,F,R
# 7 10     A,V,D,S,C,E
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data1[rowSums(sapply(data2$check_email, function(x) grepl(x,data1$emails))) > 0, "id", F]

   id
1   1
2   2
4   4
5   5
7   7
8   8
10 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can split the elements of the character vector `as.character(data1$emails)` into substrings, then we can iterate over this list with `sapply` looking for `any` value of this substring contained in `data2$check_email`. Finally we extract those values from `data1`

```
> emails <- strsplit(as.character(data1$emails), ",")
> ind <- sapply(emails, function(emails) any(emails %in% as.character(data2$check_email)))
> data1[ind,"id", drop = FALSE]
   id
1   1
2   2
4   4
5   5
7   7
8   8
10 10
```